How to create an online game for WebGL using MIrror
I was creating my own simple multiplayer game on Unity. But I'm having problems connecting to the server in the browser. I already rent a server with which I tested the game. Please explain how I can connect to my game server in the browser.
I know that you need to add a "Simple Web Browser" to the Network Manager and that you need to configure nginx.. as well as an ssl connection, Is it possible to test the game in a browser without ssl? this all sounds very difficult for a beginner..
I tried to connect to the server without any settings, but I got an error. I Googled it, they wrote that something related to ports is possible, but which port should I specify for a browser game in Network Manager? Maybe "80"(HTTP)? I also tried it.

I dont see why you'd need a web browser. But this sounds way beyond the scope of SO read [ask]
